# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Queue'

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am writing an A* search algorithm in Python for which I need the `PriorityQueue` library to store the children of a node. I've tried different things but the error remains.

I tried `import PriorityQueue, Queue` and some other things that I found online.

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue
```

This import is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using python 3, you'll need

```
import queue as Q
```

For python < 3, use

```
import Queue as Q
```

then to instantiate a PQ just use

```
q = Q.PriorityQueue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your casing; the docs specify [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) with a lowercase 'q'.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

pq = PriorityQueue()
pq.put((5, "a"))
pq.put((1, "b"))
pq.put((3, "c"))
print(pq.get()) # => (1, b)
```